# How to ensure an argument implements an interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on a project where a have a list of classes that inherit from the abstract class `Generator`. It works kind of like a *chain of responsibility*, where each class gets instantiated after the other, calling a `generate()` method. The only special thing is that each `Generator` is passed to the next, so that the next is able to call some methods of the previous one as a way to ensure that it continuos its work taking the same assumptions.

With this setup, I would like to allow each class on the chain to determine an interface that the previous one must implement, such that it knows which methods it has available.

If the class does not implement such interface, simply an error will be shown (it's a command-line tool).

I've been looking into several possibilities, but I don't really know how to perform a proper implementation of this. Can you think of a way to do this at compile time? Would I need to do run-time checks like `instanceof`?

I leave here a bit of the skeleton representing what I have now, in case it helps.

```
public abstract class Generator {
    protected Generator(Object somePrivateStuff) {/* ... */}
    public abstract void generate();
}

public class SpecialGenerator extends Generator {
    protected SpecialGenerator(Object o) { super(o); }
    public void generate() {
        // Some actual implementation
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Dynamically load all the classes extending Generator
        // via the Reflections library, and call the method generate()
        // on each one
    }
}
```

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use reflection API to get and activate methods of the previous generator.  
see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: I don't fully understand the design. Do you want to implement some sort of hybrid "chain of responsibility" design where objects of the chain automatically detect some particularities of their successors?

Comment: That's the idea @Mena, but referring to the predecessors. Each element on the chain should be able to ensure that the previous one (which should be available somehow to the current one) has certain methods.

So you suggest I do every check at run time, @YoavGur?

Comment: @DanielM that seems to differ quite a lot from the typical "chain of responsibility" pattern. 1) because objects typically know their successors, not their ancestors. 2) because it is assumed that knowledge of a successor happens contextually to a common type (i.e. a common interface). As such I'd scratch off the "chain of responsibility" pattern altogether from the definition of what you're trying to do. Might even be a little broad for a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

If you load classes dynamically, e. g. by `String` names, `instanceof` is useless because you don't know them at compile time. Instead, you should use [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-):

```
for (Class<?> clazz : loaded) {
    if (Generator.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        // instantiate
    } else {
        // print error
    }
}
```

Without knowing how exactly instantiation should be performed, it is hard to suggest more detailed code.